# Mongoose avg function by request field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, average

I want to return the average of a `Number` field by another field(the document ID field):

```
Comments.aggregate([
            {$group:
                {
                   _id: ($nid: req.adID), // here is the field I want to set to req.adID
                    adAvg:{$avg:"$stars"}
                }
            }
            ], function(err, resulat){
                if(err) {
                    res.send(String(err));
                }
                res.send(resulat);
            }
        )
```

The ID field is in the request object, `req.adID`, I didnt find an example for grouping by a query `(_id : 'req.adID')`.
My schema looks like:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema(
    {
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //scheme
        nid:Number, // ad ID
        posted: Date, // Date
        uid: Number, // user ID
        title: String, //String
        text: String, // String
        stars: Number //String
    }
);
```

Also if someone can write the return data for this query it will be great!

Comment: A bit unclear what you want to do. Is it possible for you to edit your question to include some sample data and what your expected output is from the aggregation operation, as means to clarify your question?

Comment: It is simple as that: return the average of stars by the 'nid' field. I will edit the question.

Comment: Then what's the use of `req.adID` in your aggregation, as in the statement _here is the field I want to set to req.adID_?

Comment: In the 'req.adID' I have the document ID('nid'), by this field I want to query for all documents that match it and preform 'avg()' function on the 'stars' field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your follow-up comments on the question, looks like your aggregation needs the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline to query the documents that match the `req.adID` on the nid field, your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** pipeline's _id field should have the **`$nid`** field expression so that it becomes your distinct group by key. The following pipeline should yield the needed result:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "nid": req.adID } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$nid", 
            "adAvg": { "$avg": "$stars" }
        }
    }   
]

Comments.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
    if(err) {
        res.send(String(err));
    }
    res.send(result);
})
```

Comment: Thank you @chridam, that is the function I was looking for.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: One last question, lets say I want to count all the documents that match this query, what is the proper way to do so?

Comment: Leave the **`$match`** pipeline as is but in your **`$group`** pipeline specify a group `_id` of null, as in `"$group": {
            "_id": null, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }`. An good example can be found [**here**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null).